# Sending email attachment in Mule - Why am I getting payload attachment

Tags: mule

I am sending an email with a csv attachment in Mule using the SMTP connector.

The email generated from Mule has two attachments on it.

The first is a file named `Payload`. 
The second is the file I explicitly added `myFile<date>.csv`

How can I get rid of the `Payload` attachment? From my understanding what is in Payload file should be appearing as the content of the email. But that is not quite what is happening and instead it is appearing as an attachment.

Here is what my sub-flow that sends the email looks like. The payload coming in is a csv.

```
<sub-flow name="paymentReconSendMailSubFlow">
    <set-attachment attachmentName="myFile-#[server.dateTime.format(&quot;yyyyMMddHHmmss&quot;) + '.csv']" value="#[payload]" contentType="application/csv" doc:name="Attachment"/>  
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#[null]"/>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${smtp.username}" password="${smtp.password}" connector-ref="SMTP" to="${smtp.toAddress}" from="${smtp.fromAddress}" subject="BLAH"   replyTo="${smtp.replyToAddress}" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/html" doc:name="SMTP"/>
</sub-flow>
```

And here is what I get in my inbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Mule still has the content type of the message payload set to application/csv, so thinks your null payload is a CSV. Try adding mimeType="text/plain" to the set-payload element

Comment: thanks for answering. This one has me baffled. I tired that. I still get the same result. No change.

Comment: So I found out what the issue was. It is almost what was answered here hence I'll mark this as the answer. It was mimeType on the smtp config (instead of the set-payload) element.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to serialize the csv file to a byte array before attaching?

for example:

```
  <file:inbound-endpoint path="${output.folder}" doc:name="File"/> 
  <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer  doc:name="File to String"/>
   <set-attachment value="#[message.payload]" contentType="application/csv" 
   attachmentName="#['myfile.csv']" 
   doc:name="Attachment" />
```

Let us know if is working and the issue is the serialisation of the file before sending